# windows command prompt with automatic proxy URL for internet access

Tags: python, windows, proxy, configuration, pip

I want to install python libs using pip from windows command prompt, but unable to due to no proxy settings. Internet connection requires 'Automatic proxy configuration URL' for browsers normally. What should i do for 'command prompt'. 'set HTTP_PROXY' is not working as it requires proxy server IP and port. in my case, its an  'Automatic proxy configuration URL'.

Answer (score 1):

Download the file at the automatic proxy configuration URL. It's (usually a small) [Javascript file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config). Interpret it manually (alas!) and create a proper proxy setting for `pip`.